# Is deleting an answer good or bad?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

If an answer is not useful or if it gets down votes, is it good or bad to delete the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best thing to do is always to edit it so that it is useful<sup>1</sup> and gets upvotes.

Failing that deleting a bad answer can remove bad content and stop the downvotes. However be aware that deleting downvoted answers will not protect you from an [answer ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

<sup>1</sup> Just copying content from other answers shouldn't really be considered useful, so if that's all that can be done then falling back to deleting the answer is probably best

Comment: What's an unacceptable percentage of deleted answers very roughly? 10%? Closer to 50%?

Comment: @Szymon Unfortunately those sorts of details are kept secret to avoid people gaming the system; living just on the edge of the ban. Not to mention downvotes being a contributing factor. But the usual people who come to meta with q-bans have 3 significantly (-5 ish) downvoted closed/deleted questions and no good content

Comment: Teetered on -1ing this. Personally, I would add that if somebody has already posted a good and comprehensive answer, it's better to delete your answer than to edit it such that it just repeats the same content - doing the latter just creates noise. This has happened to me a few times - the only bad answers I've ever posted have been when I've bashed out quick answers to simple questions and then realised that I've misunderstood the question or otherwise been an idiot, and usually someone less thick than me comes along and gives a correct answer by the time I realise my mistake.

Comment: @MarkAmery Would you define a copied answer as useful? (He says being all weasely and lawyerish)

Comment: @RichardTingle *I* wouldn't, no. I don't think an answer is 'useful' unless it adds something - whether that's extra detail, or a clearer explanation, or a completely different approach - that isn't present in any other answers. From what I've seen, though, when multiple people give the same correct answer, they usually all get upvoted.

Comment: @MarkAmery That can be true when they are all posted at a similar time. Regardless I've added a footnote regarding this

Comment: I think deleting answers where a person has provide a quick but incomplete information when a better/complete answer has been provided is beneficial for all. The volume of information others need to read is less.

Comment: @JamieClayton If they are substatially different (as opposed to one being a worse version of the other) I say let the voting sort it out

Comment: @RichardTingle - Totally agree that alternative (outside the box) answers are worth keeping and a voting system demonstrates it's value. I've seen some answers that have made me re-think approaches where I cherry pick parts of each answer ( or parts from multiple questions ).